# Pass Variable from View in LIMIT clause in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to create a variable which will store the number of users to be filtered. Basically, I need to check how many events a user generates within a certain number of months and then only the top number of users are used. 
I noticed that Bigquery does not have a set variable functionality, therefore I created a view which has my variables.

I have the following Bigquery SQL code.

```
WITH vars AS (
  SELECT 3 as num_months,
         200000 as num_users
)

SELECT id, count(d.value) as count_value
FROM events_data evt, unnest(evt.data) AS d, vars
WHERE  DATE(eventdate) > date_sub(current_date(), INTERVAL num_months MONTH) AND d.key='eventid'
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY count_value
LIMIT num_users
```

The use of `num_months` works perfectly within the filtering of the number months however when I try to limit the number of users within the `LIMIT` clause it gives the following error

```
Syntax error: Unexpected identifier "num_users"
```

I have even tried referencing the view as well like `vars.num_users`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
WITH params AS (
      SELECT 3 as num_months, 200000 as num_users
     )
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT id, COUNT(*) as count_value,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC) as seqnum
      FROM events_data evt, unnest(evt.data) d JOIN
           params
           ON DATE(eventdate) > date_sub(current_date(), INTERVAL num_months MONTH) AND
      WHERE d.key = 'eventid'
      GROUP BY id
     ) id CROSS JOIN
     params
WHERE seqnum <= params.num_users
ORDER BY count_value;
```

I typically call such CTEs `params`, so I renamed it.

Comment: So, there is no way to do it using LIMIT, is it?

Comment: @VarunKumar . . . If you have a question, you should ask it as a *question*, with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish.